# grails / groovy console VS war file Ambiguous method SQL

Tags: sql, grails, groovy, datasource

So working with grails run-app VS war file.

My expectation was that all I have to do to generate a war file and throw it into Tomcat was to type in    war

Code below works fine on the RUN-APP console. Code stripped down to what is not working.

```
package foo
import groovy.sql.Sql;
class FooAlertJob {
    static triggers = {
      simple name: 'mySimpleTrigger',  startDelay:5000, repeatInterval: 1000*10l
    }

    def dataSourceFoo

    def execute() {

        def sql = new Sql (dataSourceFoo)
    }
}
```

When running with tomcat and a war file built from grails I am getting (pasted below)

**Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface javax.sql.DataSource]
    [interface java.sql.Connection]]**

Googling around I did not find a solution so perhaps I am just dense.

What do I have to do to my groovy so that when I generate a war file I do not have to worry about re-testing it all ?

I have tried the obvious about fully qualifying sql as groovy.sql.SQL but I do not have a clear example of working code from run-app to war file.

Also frustrating is the groovy / grails docs does not even mention it so I am wondering if I just don't understand basics here. I am clear on runtime groovy VS compile time but still you would think that examples you copy/paste from grails documentation would work if you produced a war file.

java 1.8
Grails 2.5.3
Groovy 2.4.5

**[interface java.sql.Connection] [See nested exception: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method groovy.sql.Sql#.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface javax.sql.DataSource]
    [interface java.sql.Connection]]**

Comment: `datasourceFoo` is null

Comment: No it is not null. This is a grails application. It is defined in DataSource.groovy and works just like you see it in the grails console running the command run-app

Comment: Yes it is null. That's what the error says

Comment: Please show your DataSource.groovy.

Comment: dataSourceFoo {
            loggingSql = true
            username = "reader"
            password = "reader1"
            readOnly = TRUE
            url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Reports"
            driverClassName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"
        }

Comment: Sorry for the past above. Again the code is fine when running from grails prompt run-app. Its when you "war" it up it gets the above issue.

Comment: I have this same error and ALSO missed the [null]. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[war file generated by Grails ignores dataSource URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415672/war-file-generated-by-grails-ignores-datasource-url)

Looks like it was a palm slap to the forehead.

The Datasource needs to be defined in the production environment as that is what the war file is expecting.

Thanks everyone.